# Integral of $4x(1+x)^{-5}$ without partial fractions

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is asking me to do $\int_{0}^{\infty}{4x\over(1+x)^5}dx$

My question is, is there any way to do this *without* partial fractions. If there is a formula for equations of this type, I will gladly memorize it, I just don't think I'll have time to partial fraction expand a question like this on the P exam.

Comment: You could try the obvious substitution $y=1+x$ and see if that helps.

Comment: Let $u=1+x$.$ $

Comment: Oh... wait... then x = u-1...?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @BobbieD, I may have over thought the problem, thank you!

Comment: Not a problem.$ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=1+x,$ then $du=dx$ and so your integral is now
$$\int_{u=1}^{\infty}4(u-1)u^{-5}du=4\int_{1}^{\infty}(u^{-4}-u^{-5})du=\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

For any $a>0$
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{4x}{(a+x)^3}\,dx = \frac{2}{a}\tag{1} $$
hence by applying $\frac{d^2}{da^2}$ to both sides of $(1)$
$$ 12\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{4x}{(a+x)^5}\,dx = \frac{4}{a^3}\tag{2} $$
and by evaluating at $a=1$
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{4x\,dx}{(1+x)^5}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}.\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

Integrating by parts,
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{4x}{(1+x)^5} \, dx = \left[ -\frac{x}{(1+x)^4} \right]_0^{\infty} + \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+x)^4} \\
= 0 + \left[ -\frac{1}{3(1+x)^3} \right]_0^{\infty} = \frac{1}{3} $$

Answer (score 1):

Overkill:
One finds by integrating by parts that
$$ \frac{1}{(1+x)^5} = \frac{1}{4!}\int_0^{\infty} s^4 e^{-s(1+x)} \, ds. $$
We may insert this and change the order of integration to find
$$ I = \frac{1}{4!}\int_0^{\infty} s^4 e^{-s} \int_0^{\infty} 4xe^{-sx} \, dx \, ds, $$
integrate by parts again to find $\int_0^{\infty} xe^{-sx} \, dx = s^{-2}$, and then integrate by parts a few more times to conclude that
$$ I = \frac{1}{3!}\int_0^{\infty} s^2 e^{-s} \, ds = \frac{2!}{3!} = \frac{1}{3}. $$